# only select a subset of related objects with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.TextField(...)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'question'),
```

Now in a view I want to iterate over some questions and use the (only maybe existing) answer from request.user like:

```
questions = Questions.objects.filter(...).iterator()
for q in questions:
    try:
        a = Answer.objects.get(user=request.user, question=q)
    except Answer.DoesNotExist:
        a = None
    do_something_with(a)
```

This results in `O(#Questions)` database hits. I could use [.prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), but I don't see a way to limit the values to prefetch to `Answer`s with `user=request.user` and on a site with many users it takes a considerable amount of memory to prefetch the Answers of all users.

I think the information could be retrieved in a single query with [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra). I didn't test it yet, but I would expect something like the following to work:

```
questions = Questions.objects.extra(select={'user_answer': 'SELECT id, answer from answer where answer.user.id = %s', }, params=(request.user.id,))
```

(Not sure how this behaves if there is no answer available.)

`Questions.objects.filter(answer__user=request.user)` doesn't work, because it skips over questions that have no related `Answer` by `request.user`.

Also using two queries like:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(...).all()
users_answers = Answer.objects.filter(user=request.user, question__in=questions)
users_answers = dict((a.id, a) for a in users_answers)
for q in questions:
    a = users_answers.get(q.id)
```

is inefficient if there are many questions that match the used filter.

Is there a more pythonic way that doesn't force me to write SQL, is more easy to write and read and still is more efficient than the first variant where the `Answer`s are fetched one by one in a Python loop?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?  Is it just that you want the answers to a given question by a given user; and then the questions of those answers?

Comment: @JohnMee I want to render a list of all questions together with `request.user`'s answers. So `do_something_with(a)` above is `q.usersanswer = a` and then `questions` is given to `render()`. Does this clarify enough?